# How to implement a class that has one of either two types for an arg

Tags: c++

if I have a c++ class like:

```
class Student
{ 
    public: 

    string name;
    int assigned_number;      
};
```

and I want to use either name or number but not both for each instance, is there a way to make this an `Or` type where only one of them is required?

Comment: Comments like `// Access specifier` are clutter. The only people who'll benefit from it are those who are unlikely to understand most of your code anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you call "required"? As it stands, a `Student` has those two subobjects and there is no way around it. Maybe, what you're looking or is a so-called variant, which is basically a way that one object can appear as different objects, like `std::variant`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***If*** you are using *C++17 or above*, you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) from `<variant>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant> // For 'std::variant'

class Student
{
public:
    std::variant<std::string, int> name_and_id;
};

int main() {
    Student stud; // Create an instance of student

    // Pass a string and print to the console...
    stud.name_and_id = "Hello world!";
    std::cout << std::get<std::string>(stud.name_and_id) << std::endl;

    // Pass an integer and print to the console...
    stud.name_and_id = 20;
    std::cout << std::get<int>(stud.name_and_id) << std::endl;
}
```

`std::variant` is a new addition to C++17 and is intended to replace the unions from C and has exceptions in case of errors...

Comment: I'm glad you removed that poor advice, got my vote again. One can use [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) pre C++17 (it *was* good on you to address it, for what it's worth). Or implement their own flavor, variant types were always possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can use union.

```
#include <string>

class Student
{
    // Access specifier 
public:
    Student()
    {

    }
    // Data Members
    union
    {
        std::string name;
        int assigned_number;
    };
    ~Student()
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Student test;
    test.assigned_number = 10;
    test.name = "10";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example of how you'd create an instance?

Comment: Did you try running this? Your code segfaults on the two systems I tested.

Comment: your code has UB because you have a non-trivial destructor in a union. The code is **incorrect!**!